# What is wrong with using a primitive array as an actual type parameter in Java 5?

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile code such as the below using JDK1.5.0_u22. I get two compile errors (further below). It works fine with JDK1.6.0u30, but my project is restricted to Java 5. It also works fine if I repleace float with the wrapper class Float. Does anyone know what's going on here? A simple bug or some general restriction on the use of primitive array types in generic situations?

```
import java.util.*;
public class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<float[]> list = Arrays.asList(new float[1], new float[3]);
     float[] key = new float[2];
     int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, key, new Comparator<float[]>() {
        public int compare(float[] f1, float[] f2) {
           return f1.length - f2.length;
        }
     });
     System.out.println(index);
   }
}
```

Compile errors:

```
C:\Users\mravn\Desktop>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22"\bin\javac A.java
A.java:4: incompatible types
found   : java.util.List<<nulltype>[]>
required: java.util.List<float[]>
       List<float[]> list = Arrays.asList(new float[1], new float[3]);
                                       ^
A.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method binarySearch(java.util.List<float[]>,float[],<anonymous java.util.Comparator<float[]>>)
location: class java.util.Collections
     int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, key, new Comparator<float[]>() {
                            ^
2 errors

C:\Users\mravn\Desktop>
```

Comment: I've copied your code as is and could compile and run it without errors under jdk1.5.0_22.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788433/can-you-pass-an-int-array-to-a-generic-method-in-java this might give you some insight

Comment: Strange. Did you use the Oracle-supplied javac? Using eclipse, it works for me to.

Comment: Hmmm - i'm getting the same results as mravn using jdk1.5.0_16

Comment: works fine for me with jdk1.5.0_22

Comment: OK, maybe a platform difference?? I've got a 64-bit JDK downloaded from Oracle and running on Win7.

Comment: I just download jdk1.5.0_22 and ran "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\javac" A.java from a dos prompt and also get the errors.  I'm on a 32bit XP pro machine

Comment: Very, very interesting...I commented out everything and compiled this and ran it successfully with a return result of "1" - "System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new float[1]).size());"  I attempted to compile this - "System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new float[1], new float[3]).size());" and I received a nasty message from the compiler - "An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.5.0_22). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report."

Comment: Also just found that if I do "List<float[]> list = Arrays.asList(new float[1]);", no compiler error occurs

Comment: @ZackMacomber This is due to "float..." being compiled as "float[]"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to give the answer for the 1st compiler error and keep digging to see if I can find the one for the 2nd compiler error...

Running the following by itself produces no errors using jdk1.5.0_22:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new float[1]).size());
```

Running this by itself...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new float[1], new float[3]).size());
```

produces this nasty compiler error...

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.5.0_22). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected type: <nulltype>
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker.Type(TreeMaker.java:531)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker.Type(TreeMaker.java:525)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.boxArgs(Lower.java:2510)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitApply(Lower.java:2420)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Apply.accept(Tree.java:813)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitSelect(Lower.java:3019)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Select.accept(Tree.java:987)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitApply(Lower.java:2474)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Apply.accept(Tree.java:813)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1893)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.boxArgs(Lower.java:2517)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitApply(Lower.java:2420)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Apply.accept(Tree.java:813)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitExec(TreeTranslator.java:227)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Exec.accept(Tree.java:728)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.translate(TreeTranslator.java:54)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitBlock(TreeTranslator.java:145)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitBlock(Lower.java:2933)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$Block.accept(Tree.java:535)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator.visitMethodDef(TreeTranslator.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDefInternal(Lower.java:2267)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitMethodDef(Lower.java:2186)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$MethodDef.accept(Tree.java:478)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitClassDef(Lower.java:1989)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Tree$ClassDef.accept(Tree.java:434)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1881)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translate(Lower.java:1901)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.translateTopLevelClass(Lower.java:3070)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:487)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:592)
```

So I followed the compilers advice and did some searching on Oracle's bug database and found the bug by searching for "java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected type: ".  You can check it out here: [Primitive arrays and varargs inference leads to crash in TreeMaker.Type(TreeMaker.java:531)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6222762)

Using the Float wrapper class is the work around as you discovered.

**EDIT - answer for 2nd compiler error**

I believe the 2nd compiler error to be a bug and I've submitted it to the [Bug Database](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/)

I was able to compile the following list, key and comparator by themselves with no compiler errors:

```
List<float[]> list=new ArrayList<float[]>();
list.add(new float[] {0.0f});
list.add(new float[] {1.0f});
    
float[] key = new float[2];
     
Comparator<float[]> c = new Comparator<float[]>() {
    public int compare(float[] f1, float[] f2) { 
        return f1.length - f2.length;
    }
};
```

When I try to run "Collections.binarySearch(list, key, c)" with them, I get the "cannot find symbol" error.  If I change "float" to "Float", it compiles fine with both cases.

I believe that the list, key and comparator I posted above fulfills the binary search contract completely according to the [Java 5 spec on it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: Thanks - it turns out one can get around the first bug by just supplying a hint to the compiler: Arrays.<float[]>asList(...). For the second bug, I've found nothing except using a Comparator<Object> with two (float[]) casts in the method implementation.

Comment: Yes - I read something along the lines of Arrays.<int[]> on the Bug Database - "Arrays.binarySearch can't infer int[]" - bug id=5070671

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to compile with JDK 6 and set `-target 1.5`, then it would be possible to run it with jdk 1.5.0_22 (tried on a linux box).

Comment: Like I said, it works fine for me too using JDK6. The problem only appears with JDK5. I'm not using any compile flags, just plain javac (see posting)

Comment: This should be a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Generics don't handle primitives consistently. This is because Generics it is just a compile time addition to a single class.