# How to write mockito matcher for byte[]?

Tags: java, mockito, primitive-types, matcher

I need a complex `Matcher` for `byte[]`. The code below does not compile since `argThat` returns `Byte[]`. Is there a way to write a dedicated `Matcher` for an array of primitive types?

```
    verify(communicator).post(Matchers.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Byte[]>() {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object argument) {
            // do complex investigation of byte array
            return false;
        }
    }));
```

Comment: How about `new ArgumentMatcher<byte[]> { ... }`?

Comment: You cannot use primitive types for Generics. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types

Comment: But arrays are not primitive types, even if their elements are.

Comment: Nope. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/788445/671639 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1218369/671639 .

Comment: why not use ? or Object in the argument matcher if you dont mind a compile time warning.

Comment: @BetaRide You're confusing `T (<T> = byte[])` compared to `T[] (<T> = byte)`. You're correct that the latter doesn't compile without switching to `Byte`, but the former is the way to solve the problem. See [this example](http://ideone.com/QRGhMW), which accepts a generic parameter of type `byte[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You really can use `new ArgumentMatcher<byte[]> { ... }` here:

```
verify(communicator).post(Matchers.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        // do complex investigation of byte array
        return false;
    }
}));
```

The answers you are referring to say that `byte[]` is not a valid substitute for `T[]` (because `T[]` assumes `Object[]`, which `byte[]` is not), but in your case there is no `T[]` involved, and `byte[]`, being a subclass of `Object`, is a valid substitute for simple `T`.