# jcombobox holding array of int error

Tags: java, jcombobox

Can a Jcombobox hold an int? because i tried this and got an error.

int[] timeSched = new int[] {200,300,400,500};
        JComboBox Jcombo1 = new JComboBox(timeSched);

Comment: Use `Integer[] timeSched = new Integer[] {200,300,400,500};` instead

Comment: yea it work.. why can't i just use int? what;s the difference between that?

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, where as the `JComboBox`, via it's use generics, requires an `Object` type array. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788433/can-you-pass-an-int-array-to-a-generic-method-in-java) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types) for more details

Comment: can you show me a code in how to change the array int to time? for example 200 become 2:00, 300 to 3:00. I'm trying to do that for hours but i can't seem to get it right..

Comment: I can think of a multitude of ways you can do it.  You could just use `String` instead.  Or you could use and `int` value which represents the number of minutes since midnight (2am been 120 minutes) and then use a custom `ListCellRenderer` to render the actual value in the combobox.  Or you could use a `JSpinner` and spin the hour/minute value of a `Date` object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int[]` is not the same as `Object[]`.

Instead of `int[]` you can use `Integer[]` which is a wrapper class for the primitive `int` type, something like...

```
Integer[] timeSched = new Integer[] {200,300,400,500};
```

This allows the value to be passed to the `JComboBox`'s constructor which is expecting a generic array of `Object`s.

Remember, generics in Java don't support primitives as there base class it defined off `Object` and primitives are a special (non-object) type in Java